# Firebase Auth not updating once password reset

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase

I can't quite seem to figure out how to reset the Firebase Auth object once it has loaded for the first time.

I am looking for the bool `true` value in `auth.password.isTemporaryPassword` which forces the user to reset their password. Once the user has carried this out this procedure and reset, the `auth.password.isTemporaryPassword` remains `true`.

The only way around this I have found is to log the user out and log them in again which refreshes the auth object.

login:

```
var ref = new Firebase(environment);

$firebaseAuth(ref)
.$authWithPassword({
     email: email,
     password: password
},sessionObj)
.then(function(authData) {
    if (password.isTemporaryPassword === true) {
        $state.go('resetpassword');
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
});
```

reset password:

```
$scope.reset.oldPassword         =  "oldPass";
$scope.reset.newPassword         =  "newPass";
$scope.reset.email              =   "usermail";

ref.changePassword($scope.reset, function(err) {
    if(err) {
         ...
    }
    else {
        $state.go('home')
    }
})
```

`password.isTemporaryPassword` remains `true` until I log the user in again which seems hacky.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please include a minimal snippet that reproduces the problem into your question. It'll be a lot easier to help you then. (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`onAuth`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html) function to listen for changes to authentication state:

```js
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {

    //user authenticated & needs to change her password
    if(authData && authData.password.isTemporaryPassword) {
        $state.go('resetpassword');
    }

    //else user is logged in with valid password
    else if(authData) {

    }

    //else user is logged out
    else {

    }
});
```